# AngularJS directive scope not updating it's template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In AngularJS, I can successfully bind data from a controller to a directive.  I can also set other $scope properties in the directive and have them reflected in the template *initially*.

However, when I update the scope via the directive (after everything has loaded initially), those changes are not applied in the template.

For example...

#### Controller

```
app.controller('FooCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.bar = ['one','two','three'];
});
```

#### Directive

```
app.directive('fooDirective',function($window){
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    transclude: 'element',
    scope: {
      foo: "="
    },
    template: '<h1>{{foo}} - {{test}}</h1>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){

      scope.test = 3;

      angular.element($window).bind('resize',function(){
        console.log('the screen has resized');
        scope.test = scope.test + 1;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

#### Html

```
<body ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    <foo-directive data-foo="bar"></foo-directive>
</body>
```

All of that code correctly renders the template with the data from both the controller scope and the directive scope.  When I resize the page the console.log is hit, but the scope update is not reflected in the template.  Why is that the case and how can I work around this?

## Here's a [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/JhENPCpMP06wvo39jnqN?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are handling a jQuery event outside of the angular context, you need to call $apply to trigger a $digest:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){

  scope.test = 3;

  angular.element($window).bind('resize',function(){
    scope.$apply(function() {
        console.log('the screen has resized');
        scope.test = scope.test + 1; 
    });

  });
}
```

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lo193z8nlujWbzDuZczv?p=preview)

Comment: That seems to do the trick!  It's hard to know when angular will call $apply() for you.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but I provided an answer about when you can tell to call $apply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295145/when-is-scope-apply-necessary-for-dealing-with-objects-arrays-with-angular/24297702#24297702